# Sufficient knowledge to Start Studying Group Theory

Tags: group-theory

I am wondering what sufficient knowledge/ maths background is needed to begin studying group theory? Additionally, does anyone here think there is benefit to applying it to the field of microeconomic theory? This is self study so there is no timeline and I can fill gaps as they occur. I didn't see this question posted before but please feel free to link if it has.

Thanks so much!

Keith

Comment: I would say nothing is necessary if the group theory is built up "step by step".

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the response. Do you know of any resources that treat it as a "step-by-step" concept? Books, papers etc.?

Comment: Yes, many books and lecture notes, too. See the duplicate for these step-by-step books.

Comment: No background is necessary, except maybe some knowledge of basic mathematical notation (functions, sets, etc.). I do not think there is any application to microeconomic theory. There are applications in theoretical physics and chemistry.